# What is the best way to make a recursive running total query performant in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I'm trying to do a query like the following that should create a running total for different accounts:

```
SELECT 
    a.`date`,
    a.`account`,
    a.`key`,
    a.`balance`,
    SUM(b.`balance`) AS 'running_balance'
FROM `balances` a
JOIN `balances` b ON a.`date` >= b.`date` AND a.`account` = b.`account`
GROUP BY a.`date`, a.`account`, a.`key`, a.`balance`;
```

This works great for smaller data sets, but when I approach around 100,000 rows, it has serious performance issues.

What can I do to make this more performant?  Which columns should I consider indexing?

Comment: Consider providing full DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Comment: Upgrade to a modern DBMS that supports window functions?